# When Ubuntu 18.04.1 Server is asked to preinstall Docker, it ends up in /snap

Tags: server, 18.04, docker

This is confusing because the following doesn't work:

```
# dpkg --list | grep [d]ocker     # (verify that Docker is installed)
```

As I'm new to Docker and just learning it, I would like to know whether a) I should not have asked Ubuntu server installation to preinstall Docker and b) whether to proceed to a formal installation instead (next time) or anyway (this time):

```
# apt install docker.io
```

I'm sure it wasn't wrong to have Docker in */snap*, but it doesn't match tutorials I'm reading.

Would someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 2):

Snap is a recent, alternative packaging concept from Canonical, separate from the Advanced Packaging Tool (`apt`). You'll notice that `$ echo $PATH` will likely manifest */snap/bin* at the end. This makes it so that any command you use, if it's not caught by something existing earlier in *PATH*, may be done with something out of Snap.

Docker, as occasioned during the installation of Ubuntu 18.04.1 Server, will be in Snap (as opposed to being found among Debian packages). It's how Canonical decided to install it when chosen from the list of possible installations early on.

Notice that `$ docker --version` does work and Docker is available and usable from Snap just as it might be if you installed it using `apt-get`. (Installing via `apt` happens to be a lot more involved because you'll have to add a repository you probably do not already have, plus a key and perform some other actions. `apt install docker.io` will not do it.)

It's possible to install Docker (the hard way, using `apt`) alongside the Snap way, but there is nothing to be gained from it.

Last, a lack of familiarity with Docker will only begin to reveal other Docker-associated commands and practices which are not always going to be available as a direct result of simply having installed Docker. Such problems will have to be worked out anyway and are not related to Snap. Their solution may be in `apt` and not be available (yet) in Snap, but that doesn't mean they will fail to work with a Snap-installed Docker.